# Filter NSSCrollView using date

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nsscrollview

I'm having problem filtering an NSScrollViews contents using it's date column.

I have an Entity that it's contains several attributes, such as **Name** , **AccountNumber** , **DateOfPurchase** , etc. This entity is bound to an NSArraycontroller.

Also, I have an NSScrollView that it's columns is bounded to this NSArrayController.

The problem is that I want to filter this NSScrollView records to show just the records that they are limited by interval of 2 date. ( like : after 10/02/2010 and before 05/05/2011 )

What should I do to do this ?

Comment: I guess you’re confusing `NSScrollView` with `NSTableView`. A scroll view doesn’t have columns; a table view is (usually) enclosed in a scroll view.

Comment: @bavarious, yes, maybe you right because I used TableView in IB but when I try to make an outlet from it's control into my header file I can see the outlet type is NSScrollview. I will be glad if you mentioned it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using FilterPredicate :

```
    NSDate *afterDate=[balanceDateAfter objectValue];
    NSDate *beforeDate=[balanceDateBefore  objectValue];
    NSComparisonResult duration=[beforeDate timeIntervalSinceDate:afterDate];

    duration=duration/3600;
    duration=duration/24;

    NSLog(@"After Date is : %@",afterDate);
    NSLog(@"Before Date is : %@",beforeDate);

    [checkInBalanceArray setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(checkDate >= %@) AND (checkDate <= %@)", afterDate, beforeDate]];

    [checkOutBalanceArray setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(checkDate >= %@) AND (checkDate <= %@)", afterDate, beforeDate]];
```